# How to go back from one viewcontroller to other viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, viewcontroller

I have a simple one for you guys. I have created a back button on a `UITableviewController`, and want to set that back button to my other `UIViewController`(NewTableViewController).

here i implemement back button

```
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(NewTableViewController.back(sender:)))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

and action is

```
func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

   // perform your custom action 
   //....
   // go back to the previuos view controller 
   _ = navigationController?.navigationController?.self.dismiss(animated: true)

 }
```

but i am unable to go back

Thanks for the help you guys. Please tell me what I am missing.

Comment: If you push, you dont need to create the back button your self, if you use modal show, you dont use `popViewController`, but use `self.dismiss`

Comment: navigationController?.popViewController

Comment: You should add the code as a snippet instead of image :)

Comment: Yea that probably would have been smarter... @AhmadF

Comment: Try this : `func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if let navController = self.navigationController {
            navController.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
`

Comment: @MuseerAnsari that also seems to no work :/

Comment: @MuseerAnsari I changed it to self.dismiss instead of popViewController and it worked, thank you so much!

Comment: `func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {});
    }
`

Comment: pleas mind if its works thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for **swift 3**

If you use model view controller

```
func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {});
}
```

**OR**

If you use push

```
func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if let navController = self.navigationController {
       navController.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```